# How to impose Google App Engine's DeadlineExceededException?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

I'd like to take the attitude that if my server-side is too slow, just throw an exception and send back a meaningful error message to the client. I am arbitrarily setting this time limit to 5 seconds and will tweak it as needed.

I see that App Engine has `ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getRemainingMillis()` which gives us the number of milliseconds we have left before it throws a `DeadlineExceedException` and times us out.

I'd like to do something similar, but imposing my own 5-second restriction over GAE's 60-second restriction (again, for right now doesn't matter if I pick 5-seconds or 40-seconds, as long as they are stricter than what GAE imposes). I'd like to write a server-side handler/servlet that starts a 5-second timer. If the request does not return inside that amount of time it throws an exception and returns to the client:

```
public class MyTimedServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
        // Start 5-second timer
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);

        try {
            timer.start();
            response = handleRequest(request);
        }
        catch(TimeException timerException) {
            response = ResponseFactory.newTimeExceededResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the GAE API that resembles the `Timer` object that I'm looking for.

I'm already planning on making use of multihthreading every request via `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory().newRequestThread(...)`, so I don't want to waste one of these (I only get 10 at a time!) threads to create a background "*Timer Thread*" unless I absolutely have to.

So I ask: does GAE have something like this out of the box, and if I have to roll my own, how do I go about doing so? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any asynchronous task (that don't follow the normal flow) in your code involves a new thread execution, in this case this task is to count the time.**

However you can use the classes [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) & [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) both of them included in the App-Engine JRE white list.

Example code: not tested just a guide.

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    Timer timer;
    HttpServletResponse response;   

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)...{
        int seconds = 5;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new DeadLine(), seconds * 1000);     

        /* the rest of your code here */
    }

    class DeadLine extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {      
            response.getWriter().print("Error: deadline reached.");     
        }
      }
}
```

Read this article about [job scheduling in Java,](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Marlon Jerez Isla (+1) - App Engine frontend instances only allow you to spawn 10 threads at a time. I assume each one of these `Timer`/`TimerTask` combos would eat up 1 of these available threads? Or does App Engine not count them against the 10?

Comment: yes it counts, 1 more thread, Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks.